# Proceedings of Royal Society Compilation error

Tags: compiling

I am trying to compile the following (i.e., Author_tex.tex):
https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/52fdfa7134a287a85245b4bf

and I receive the error: `! LaTeX Error: File RSPA_LOGO-color' not found.`

I have downloaded all the files in one folder, but the figures don't show up at all while compiling. Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `pdflatex` to compile, it seems. And those figures are in `.eps` format. Hence you are getting the error as `pdflatex` can't take `.eps` figures.

Remedies:
Try one of these.

1. Use `xelatex` to compile → `xelatex Author_tex`
2. Compile using `latex` → `latex Author_tex` and then `dvips Author_tex` and then `ps2pdf Author_tex` to get the pdf file.
3. Add `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` to your preamble and compile using `pdflatex` → `pdflatex --shell-escape Author_tex`
4. Add `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to your preamble and compile with `pdflatex`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used `\usepackage{epstopdf}` and it worked instantly.